# How to Send knockoutjs data to ajax

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm new on knockoutjs. I'm developing a project with knockoutjs. When I'm trying to send the data through ajax. I'm getting error. How to send the knockout converted json data to ajax? When I'm trying to alert the json data to check, data not showing. I'm posing this question first time. Sorry if there is any mistake.

My code is :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>INDIATECH247</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooltipster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/tooltipster-punk.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Tooltip Js Started Here
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            theme: 'tooltipster-punk'});


    // Default Grid View of Data
    if($('.row').hasClass('active')){
            $('#grid').removeClass('db')
            $('#row').addClass('db')}
        else{
            $('#row').removeClass('db')}
    if($('.grid').hasClass('active')){
            $('#row').removeClass('db')
            $('#grid').addClass('db')}
            else{
                $('#grid').removeClass('db')}

     // Show and Hide View Button
     $('.checked').change(function(){
         var no=$(".yes input:checkbox:checked").length;
         if(no>1 || no==0){
             $('.view').addClass('dn')
             }
             else{
                 $('.view').removeClass('dn')
                 }
         })

    //View Full Info ///////////// Working able to remove selected data
    $('.view').click(function(){
        //var selected=$(".yes").has("input:checkbox:checked")
        //$((selected) ).remove();
        $('#fullinfo').addClass('db')
        })

    // Grid and Row view of data        
    $('.row').click(function(e) {
        $('.grid').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        //Row View on click Started Here
        if($('.row').hasClass('active')){
            $('#grid').removeClass('db')
            $('#row').addClass('db')}
        else{
            $('#row').removeClass('db')}    
    });             
    $('.grid').click(function(e) {
        $('.row').removeClass('active');            
        $(this).addClass('active');
        //Grid View on Click Started Here
        if($('.grid').hasClass('active')){
            $('#row').removeClass('db')
            $('#grid').addClass('db')}
            else{
                $('#grid').removeClass('db')}
    });

     // Find button coding
     $('#find').click(function(){
         $('#searchbutton').addClass('dn');
         $('#search').removeClass('dn')

         })

    });
</script>

</head>
<div class="page-header">
    <header class="center-auto">
        <div class="logo fl">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">INDIATECH247</a>
        </div>
        <nav class="fl">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.php" title="">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="customers.php" title="">Customers</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="invoiceall.php" title="">Invoice</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
<div class="btn-group top-buttons">
            <div class="btn btn-success tooltip" title="Add New Customer"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <a href="addcustomer.php" title="">Add Customer</a></div>
            <div class="btn btn-success tooltip" title="Add New Product"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">Add Product</a></div>
            <div class="btn btn-success tooltip" title="Create Invoice"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>  <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">Create Invoice</a></div>
        </div>
    </header>
  </div>
<div class="center-auto">
 <div class="hed">Add Customer</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
// View Model (this is a representation of the data for this particular view/webpage)
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.Fname = ko.observable();
self.Lname = ko.observable();
self.Email = ko.observable();
self.Mobile = ko.observable();
self.Bname = ko.observable();
self.Address = ko.observable();
self.City = ko.observable();
self.Pincode = ko.observable();
self.isValid = ko.computed(function(){
   return self.Fname() && self.Email() && self.Mobile();
});

};  
// Start knockout!
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
var jsonData = ko.toJS(ViewModel);
$('#submit').click(function(){
alert(ko.toJSON(jsonData));
$.ajax({
    url:"includes/addcustomer.php",
            type:"Post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:jsonData,
            success:function(data){
                $(".check").text(data);
                }

    })

})
});
 </script>
<form>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">First Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" data-bind="value:Fname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">Last Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"data-bind="value:Lname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">Email</span>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" data-bind="value:Email, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">Mobile No</span>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" data-bind="value:Mobile, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">Business Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="bname" id="bname" data-bind="value:Bname, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">Address</span>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" data-bind="value:Address, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">City</span>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" data-bind="value:City, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <div class="span6"><span class="span2">Pin Code</span>
    <input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" data-bind="value:Pincode, valueUpdate: 'afterkeyup'"/></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" data-bind="enable: isValid" data-bind="submit: ViewModel.bind($root,$data)" method="POST"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Customer</button>
 </form>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)" id="jsondata" class="check"></pre>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
var jsonData = ko.toJS(ViewModel);
$('#submit').click(function(){
alert(ko.toJSON(jsonData));
```

`ViewModel` is a function, so you can't turn it into json. You'll need to create an instance of it, and keep a reference to it. Try this:

```
var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel );
var jsonData = ko.toJS(myViewModel );
$('#submit').click(function(){
alert(ko.toJSON(jsonData));
...
```

Comment: Thanks Xander for quick reply. After updating the above code when I click on alert It's showing blank with {}. It's not working as we need.